# Shading Under a Line

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

I am trying to shade the area under this graph:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,line width=1pt]

\begin{axis}[
color= black,
xmin=0, 
xmax=1250, 
ymin=0, 
ymax=1250, 
axis equal image, 
axis x line=left,
axis y line=middle,
%xticklabels={}, 
%yticklabels={},
font=\scriptsize,
%ticks=none,
%extra x ticks=0,
%extra y ticks=0,
xlabel={Corn},
ylabel={Tomatoes},
]

%\draw (0,675) -- (1000,0);
\draw [thick, red] plot [smooth] coordinates {(0,675) (200,650) (400,600) 
(600,500) (800,300) (1000,0)};
%\draw [thick, red!20, fill=red!20] (0,0) -- (0,675) -- (1000,0) -- cycle;
\filldraw[black] (0,675) circle (0.03cm) node[above right, scale=0.9] 
{$(0,675)$};
\filldraw[black] (200,650) circle (0.03cm) node[below, scale=0.9] 
{$(200,650)$};
\filldraw[black] (400,600) circle (0.03cm) node[above right, scale=0.9] 
{$(400,600)$};
\filldraw[black] (600,500) circle (0.03cm) node[above right, scale=0.9] 
{$(600,500)$};
\filldraw[black] (800,300) circle (0.03cm) node[above right, scale=0.9] 
{$(800,300)$};
\filldraw[black] (1000,0) circle (0.03cm) node[above right, scale=0.9] 
{$(1000,0)$};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
```

What I had done was filled in the line that I drew and then drew a triangle right under it to fill in the rest of the area. Ultimately, this would suffice for what I wanted to have as the picture, but I figured that there would be an easier and more effective way than what I am doing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The perhaps simplest option is to draw the curve with `\addplot` and use `fill` as well as `\closedcycle`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,line width=1pt]

\begin{axis}[
color= black,
xmin=0, 
xmax=1250, 
ymin=0, 
ymax=1250, 
axis equal image, 
axis x line=left,
axis y line=middle,
%xticklabels={}, 
%yticklabels={},
font=\scriptsize,
%ticks=none,
%extra x ticks=0,
%extra y ticks=0,
xlabel={Corn},
ylabel={Tomatoes},
]

%\draw (0,675) -- (1000,0);
\addplot [thick, red,fill=blue,smooth] coordinates {(0,675) (200,650) (400,600) 
(600,500) (800,300) (1000,0)} \closedcycle;
%\draw [thick, red!20, fill=red!20] (0,0) -- (0,675) -- (1000,0) -- cycle;
\filldraw[black] (0,675) circle (0.03cm) node[above right, scale=0.9] 
{$(0,675)$};
\filldraw[black] (200,650) circle (0.03cm) node[below, scale=0.9] 
{$(200,650)$};
\filldraw[black] (400,600) circle (0.03cm) node[above right, scale=0.9] 
{$(400,600)$};
\filldraw[black] (600,500) circle (0.03cm) node[above right, scale=0.9] 
{$(600,500)$};
\filldraw[black] (800,300) circle (0.03cm) node[above right, scale=0.9] 
{$(800,300)$};
\filldraw[black] (1000,0) circle (0.03cm) node[above right, scale=0.9] 
{$(1000,0)$};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

More options become available if you load the `fillbetween` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5,line width=1pt]

\begin{axis}[
color= black,
xmin=0, 
xmax=1250, 
ymin=0, 
ymax=1250, 
axis equal image, 
axis x line=left,
axis y line=middle,
%xticklabels={}, 
%yticklabels={},
font=\scriptsize,
%ticks=none,
%extra x ticks=0,
%extra y ticks=0,
xlabel={Corn},
ylabel={Tomatoes},
]

%\draw (0,675) -- (1000,0);
\addplot [thick, red,smooth,name path=A] coordinates {(0,675) (200,650) (400,600) 
(600,500) (800,300) (1000,0)} ;
\addplot [name path=B,draw=none] coordinates {(0,0) (1000,0)};
\addplot [orange] fill between [of=A and B];
%\draw [thick, red!20, fill=red!20] (0,0) -- (0,675) -- (1000,0) -- cycle;
\filldraw[black] (0,675) circle (0.03cm) node[above right, scale=0.9] 
{$(0,675)$};
\filldraw[black] (200,650) circle (0.03cm) node[below, scale=0.9] 
{$(200,650)$};
\filldraw[black] (400,600) circle (0.03cm) node[above right, scale=0.9] 
{$(400,600)$};
\filldraw[black] (600,500) circle (0.03cm) node[above right, scale=0.9] 
{$(600,500)$};
\filldraw[black] (800,300) circle (0.03cm) node[above right, scale=0.9] 
{$(800,300)$};
\filldraw[black] (1000,0) circle (0.03cm) node[above right, scale=0.9] 
{$(1000,0)$};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you!